# On Page Reload, "Go To Cart" button not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, 3-tier

I want to make a button Go To Cart visible after adding a product into cart. But when page gets reload it shows Add to cart button only

/*This is my presentation layer code*/

```
    protected void ddlimginfo_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName=="addtocart")
            {
                Label price = e.Item.FindControl("lblprice") as Label;
                string prc = price.Text;
                DateTime pdate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now);
                string postdate = (pdate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                Button btnaddcart = e.Item.FindControl("btnaddcart") as Button;
                Button btngocart = e.Item.FindControl("btngocart") as Button;

                //balobj.dalCart((Session["uip"]).ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(Sessio

n["id"]), qty, prc,pdate);
            //DateTime existingDate =Convert.ToDateTime(balobj.getdate((Session["uip"]).ToString()));
            //string exdate = (existingDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            balobj.dalCart(Convert.ToString(Session["uip"]), Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]), 1, prc, pdate);
            if ((Session["uip"]) != null)
            {

                Session["count"] = balobj.cartcount((Session["uip"]).ToString());
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = balobj.balgocart(Convert.ToString(Session["uip"]), Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]));

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    //Session["count"] = balobj.cartcount((Session["uip"]).ToString());
                    btnaddcart.Visible = false;
                    btngocart.Visible = true;
                    Response.Redirect("infoproduct.aspx");

                }
                else
                {

                    //Session["count"] = balobj.cartcount((Session["uip"]).ToString());
                    btnaddcart.Visible = true;
                    btngocart.Visible = false;
                    Response.Redirect("infoproduct.aspx");

                }
                //Response.Write(Session["count"]);
                //Response.End();
                //Response.Redirect("infoproduct.aspx");
            }
```

/*This is my BAL code*/

```
//Go to cart button visible
        public DataTable balgocart(string uip, int proid)
        {

            try
            {
                return dalobj.dalgocart(uip, proid);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                dalobj = null;
            }

        }
```

/*This is my DAL code*/

```
//Code to visible button go to cart
        public DataTable dalgocart(string uip, int proid)
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("spbtngocart", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("spuip", uip);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("spproid", proid);

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What does your `spbtngocart` do and return?

Comment: DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE spbtngocart(IN spuip VARCHAR(30),IN spproid BIGINT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM cart WHERE userip=spuip AND productid=spproid;
END//
DELIMITER

Comment: Can you try binding the control again?

Comment: it returns cart's information according to IP address and product id. Means  if I open product detail page and if I add that product to the cart then according to IP adrress and selected product it is returning information. I am just taking it in datatable and checking whether dt count is>0 then add to cart button should be invisible and go to cart should be visible.

Comment: i tried. But those controls are in my datalist. Hence not able to find.

Comment: Which control are you using to display in UI?

Comment: asp button control

Comment: Not for button. the main control is it repeater, datagridview?

Comment: @RichaGarg... Thank you but I solved it. I have just created an another page with goto cart button... and it is working.

Comment: the main control is datalist.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rebind the control after making changes as

```
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: yup... I got it